# Is is possible to determine if a given number is xor combination of some numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, binary, bit-manipulation, xor

I have been given a number Y which is ($a$ **xor** $b$ **xor** $c$ **xor** $d$ **xor** $e$ ) of some numbers ($a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$) and another no X. Now i have to determine if X is a xor combination of ($a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$)

e.g - ($a$ **xor** $d$) , ($b$ **xor** $c$ **xor** $e$) , ( $a$ **xor** $e$ )

What i know clearly is that lets say X= ($b$ **xor** $d$) , Now if I xor X and Y i get 
($a$ **xor** $c$ **xor** $e$), as ( $b$ **xor** $b$=0 ) and if it was some number not a xor combination (say $p$ ) then i would have got ($a$ **xor** $b$ **xor** $c$ **xor** $d$ **xor** $e$ **xor** $p$)

How should i approach this question?

Comment: It’s a linear algebra question.

Comment: How should I approach it? I am using properties of boolean operators

Comment: Use your knowledge of linear algebra.

Comment: Can you please explain a little? :)

Comment: Regard bitwise representation of the numbers as vectors over ring of integers modulo 2. Then XOR is a sum of such vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that your numbers are $n$-bit long. Then you can think of them as elements of the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. The number $X$ can be written as an XOR of $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ if $X$ is in the linear span of $a_1,\ldots,a_m$. In order to determine whether $X$ is in the linear span of $a_1,\ldots,a_m$, you can use Gaussian elimination.